# Wicket version is it always a good idea to upgrade to the latest?

Tags: version, wicket

Is it ever a bad idea to upgrade to the latest version of Wicket?  Lets say I have a very large project with an early release of Wicket. If I update to the latest, would everything have to be retested for any run time errors? Or would the updates in Wicket be backwards compatible?

I ask because this is the scenario I currently face, and I am not sure if it is worth upgrading if there is a possibility of hidden bugs, and will have to spend countless man hours retesting every functionality with each Wicket upgrade.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is a good idea to create another branch of your project with new version of Wicket and try to migrate.

There are API breaks from one major version to another, so, it may take a lot of time even to deploy the project without any compilation errors. In some cases there are very different approaches in different versions to achive same functionality.

For example:

To add header contributor in wicket 1.4 you used:

```java
    public class MyPage extends WebPage {
         add(HeaderContributor.forJavaScript(YuiLib.class,
                                  "yahoo-dom-event/yahoo-dom-event.js"));
    }
```

And in wicket 1.5 you need to override component's `renderHead` method to achive this:

```java
    public class MyPage extends WebPage {
        public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response) {
            response.renderJavaScriptReference( new PackageResourceReference (
                              YuiLib.class, "yahoo-dom-event/yahoo-dom-event.js" ) 
                             );
        }
    }
```

I don't say that newer versions worse then the older ones (no, they are better), but it will take time to migrate. And if you will do this right (according to [migration guides](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Migrations)) - you can not be afraid of runtime errors caused by new versions.

One more thing, that if you will decide to migrate to latest wicket version - 7.x, then you must also upgrade your jdk at least to 7 version and use Servlet 3 compatible container (watch your app server opportunities).

Comment: I've done a couple of version migrations too, and what I found very useful is to look at your code and the migration guide and you can make a pretty good estimate about how long migration will take. Then you can decide whether it's worth the effort.

Comment: Agreed. And there is another problem that if you use, for example, wicket 1.4 and decided to migrate to 7 version, then you must analyze all migration guides consistently - 1.4 -> 1.5 -> 6 -> 7.